# Constraints in Swift are not doing what I want

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Can anyone explain to a newbie what i am doing wrong when i am trying to design my own `UITableViewCell` with Prototype cell in Xcode.

This is what what i want to do. 
Have a simple 50x50 pix imageView pinned 10 points left from the content view (Cell) pinned 10 points from top (Constraints: height 50, width 50, Anchor left container with 10 pixr)

Then I want to add a label 10 points right of this ImageView. 
So i add a label and pin it 10 points left to the Bell Imageview, pin to top, pin it 10 points from the container and set the height of the label.

Everything looks fine in the designer, but as soon as i run the app in the simulator the label is on top of the Bell imageview

I know I can use stackviews, but i want to understand how it works :)

[image: Result]

Comment: Run your app and switch to the View Debugger. Do you see any exclamation marks? Runtime issues?

Comment: Try setting height and width of the image to 50px

Comment: @chirag90 i have set the image to 50x50 in constraints but IT dosent make a difference

Comment: @matt There is no errors

Comment: Maybe your table view is not using the storyboard cell prototype. Do you register your cell class with the table view? Show some table view controller code please.

Comment: @matt :  Is it this code you want to see ?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DropInCustomCell") as! DropInCustomCell
                
        return cell
    }


I have my own UITableViewCell class set and the correct identifier sett in the interface builder.

Comment: @BluE_MoOn Add top and bottom anchor from image view to content view and then, give leading anchor to label from imageview and vertically center it to image view.

Comment: I still can’t reproduce the issue. Can you make a demo project with this one view controller?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either.

Comment: I cant reproduce it on a new project either.     I am pulling my hair out over this. 

There must be something wrong with my Project settings. If add a simple label an tries to anchor it 10 points from right, then xcode decides to put in way out of the canvas on the left side. I have to put it minus 180 to get it into the View of the cell.   Did a test where manually added a label on the right siden without any constraints. Clicked the "Add missing constraints" and xcode put the label way outside cell view. The values of the automatic constraints seems ok, but not in the designer

Comment: We can’t see all the constraints (e.g. you expanded the constraints under the “content view” but not those under the “bell” nor “my text label”), but undoubtedly there’s some runtime issue. Likely, they’re just unsatisfiable, in which case you’d see them listed in the console (probably scrolled out of view by the time you did your screen snapshot) or under runtime issues. The other (very unlikely possibility) is that one or more of the constraints has been flagged to not be included at runtime. But there’s not enough here to diagnose.

Comment: Run app, pause execution, and at the `(lldb)` prompt, type `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` (or if you paused in a Swift frame, `expr -l objc++ -O --  [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]`). Then edit the question and include that output.

Comment: I tried to Clean build,  restart xcode several times, but after a complete restart of my macbook it suddenly worked .. hmm.

Comment: Go ahead and post that as an answer and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Or if you don’t feel it’s worth of an answer, just delete this question entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The solution: I am really emberassed to say that a restart of my Macbook was the simple solution. I tried restarting Xcode, clean building, deleting first with no luck. After a complete restart of my computer everything worked as it should.

I should have tried that first, but i really tought that cleanbuild, xcode-restart should do the trick if this was a xcode problem.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you set the height of the cell using `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` ? To me it looks like the cell is not being properly sized.

Comment: Its set to 100 in code, but it doesnt really matter